# How can I create duplicate form in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, duplicates, clone

I am trying to duplicate form based on user input.
example,

```
<div>How many members are in your team? </div>
 <input type="number" class="numOfMember">
 <form id="memberInfo">
  <div>What is your name?</div>
   <input type="text">
 </form>
```

so I think I will limit .numOfMember up to 12 people.
If user types 5, I want to make five same #memberInfo form in same page.
I think I can start like this,

```
<scritp>
 $(.numOfMember).
</script>
```

should I have to use clone or appendTo?

Comment: You probably do not want to duplicate form, you want to render only inputs and send them in the same form. Hold on a minute, I'll be back with a snippet in a minute :)

Answer (score 0):

with JQuery is quite simple if you want to do this, just grab the html structure you are trying to replicate with the .html() method:

```
   var form = $("#memberInfo").html();
```

then just make a loop for the ammount of times you want to repeat this, using the same function.

```
for(x in 10){
     $("#targetContaier").html(form);
   }
```

for this you will ned a target container like a div:

```
<div id="targetContaier"><!--new form goes here--></div>
```

your could use other looping methods for this like $.each() but for now this right what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to replicate form content for which you could use this

```
<div>How many members are in your team? </div>
<input type="number" class="numOfMember">
<form id="memberInfo">  
    <div>What is your name?</div>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

jquery

```
$(".numOfMember").change(function(){
  if($(".numOfMember").val() < 12) {
    $("#memberInfo").html("");
    for(i=0;i<$(".numOfMember").val();i++) {
      $("#memberInfo").append("<div>What is your name?</div><br><input type='text'/>");
    }
  }
})
```